# How do I get the mother to upgrade my items?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

I have saved over 60 maiamais, and I haven't had anything upgraded.  What do I have to do to get the mother to upgrade my items?

Answer (score 5):

In order for her to upgrade the items, they need to be owned, not rented items. Once you have something that isn't a rented item, you can give them to her and she will upgrade them by sucking them in and spitting them out. All of the standard items are upgradable.

Answer (score 0):

When you find 10 of the 100 lost Maiamais and return them to Mother Maiamai, she will give you the option to upgrade one of your items. She will then take it and upgrade it. BUT, you have to own the item by buying it from Ravio's shop.